# Is there an "Immediate Window" in the Dart Editor / Debugger?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Is there any way to try Dart expressions and execute commands while in a debug breakpoint?

Like in Chrome Developer Bar, Firebug or Visual Studio Immediate Window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not yet.
Star http://dartbug.com/3293 to track its progress.

A similar feature, a REPL (read-eval-print-loop) is tracked with http://dartbug.com/4409.